# (p++)->x Why are the parentheses unnecessary? (K&R)

Tags: c

From page 123 of [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0876925964) by K&R:

> (p++)->x increments p after accessing x. (This last set of parentheses is unnecessary. Why?)

Why is it unnecessary considering that `->` binds stronger than `++`?

EDIT: Contrast the given expression with `++p->x`, the latter is evaluated as `++(p->x)` which would increment `x`, not `p`. So in this case parentheses *are* necessary and we must write `(++p)->x` if we want to increment `p`.

Comment: How would it be ambiguous without parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly because `->` <s>binds stronger</s> than `++`. (it doesn't, thanks @KerrekSB.)

> increments p **after** accessing x.

So first you access `x` of `p`, then you increment `p`. That perfectly matches the order of evaluation of the `->` and the `+` operators.

**Edit: aww, these edit's...**

So what happens when you write `++p->x` is that it **could be** interpreted either as `++(p->x)` or as `(++p)->x` (which one is actually chosen is just a matter of language design, K&R thought it would be a good idea to make it evaluate as in the first case). The thing is that this ambiguity doesn't exist in the case of `p++->x`, since it can only be interpreted as `(p++)->x`. The other alternatives, `p(++->x)`, `p(++->)x` and `p++(->x)` are really just syntactically malformed "expressions".

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. Why is any kind of "binding strength" important? There isn't even a *parsing* ambiguity in the expression...

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe because OP uses it similarly to "precedence" or "enforced order of evaluation"? Of course there's no ambiguity, but it seems to me that he's asking about what the *code* does and not what the *parser* does. (Yes, looking closer I even realize that they are of the same precedence and there's no ambiguity whatsoever because the post-increment operator couldn't work in any other way - but still.) And see, I upvoted "NikosC"'s explanation anyway :)

Comment: Evaluation does not proceed as described here. The value used to access its `x`is the result of `p++`. In that sense, it is `p++` that is evaluated first. But its result happens to be the value of `p` before the increment, so that value is the pointer used for the access.

Comment: According to K&R `->` binds stronger. E.g. the expression `++p->x` is evaluated as `++(p->x)` which would increment `x`, not `p`.

Comment: @Mr.Roland Prefix increment is not a postfix operator so has not the same predecence. In `p++->x` the `++` operator is the postfix increment operator and as a postfix operator it has the same predecence as the (postfix) `->` operator,

Comment: @ouah In K&R page 49 `->` has a higher precedence than any unary operator. Did that change in later C versions?

Comment: @Mr.Roland in `p++`, `++` is not an unary operator but a postfix operator. Postfix operators all have higher precedence than unary operator. `++p` here `++` is an unary operator.

Answer (score 5):

The only other possible interpretation is:

```
p++(->x)
```

and that doesn't mean anything. It's not even valid. The *only* possible way to interpret this in a valid way is `(p++)->x`.

Answer (score 3):

The maximal munch strategy says that `p++->x` is divided into the following preprocessing tokens:

`p` then `++` then `->` then `x`

In `p++->x` expression there are two operators, the postfix `++` operator and the postifx `->` operator. Both operators being postfix operators, they have the same precedence and there is no ambiguity in parsing the expression. `p++->x` is equivalent to `(p++)->x`.

For `++p->x` expression, the situation is different.

In `++p->x`, the `++` is not a postfix operator, it is the `++` unary operator. C gives  postfix operators higher precedence over all unary operators and this is why `++p->x` is actually equivalent to `++(p->x)`.

**EDIT:** I changed the first part of the answer as a result of Steve's comment.

Comment: Maximal munch just means that `p++->x` is lexed (that is, divided into preprocessing tokens) as `p`, `++`, `->`, `x`. Likewise it says that `++p->x` is lexed as `++`, `p`, `->`, `x`, and for example that `+++x` is lexed as `++`, `+`, `x` not `+`, `++`, `x` or `+`, `+`, `+`, `x`. The munch rule says *nothing* about what the operands are going to be of the operators in that token sequence, it just tells you how to get a token sequence from the characters in the source file. Precedence and associativity apply at a later stage of translation.

Comment: @SteveJessop using the maximal munch as a justification for precedence was clumsy, I edited the answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Both post-increment and member access operator are postfix expressions and bind the same. Considering that they apply to the primary or postfix expression to the left, there can't be ambiguity.

In

```
p++->x
```

The postfix-++ operator can apply only to the expression to the left of it (i.e. to `p`).

Similarly ->x can only be an access to the expression to its left, which is `p++`. Writing that expression as `(p++)` is not needed, but also does no harm.

The "after" in your description of the effects, does not express temporal order of increment and member access. It only expresses that the result of `p++` is the value `p` had before the increment and that that value is the value used for the member access.

Answer (score 1):

The expresion `p++` results in a pointer with the value of `p`. Later on, the `++` part is performed, but for the purposes of interpreting the expression, it may just as well not be there. `->x` makes the compiler add the offset for the member `x` to the original address in `p` and access that value.

If you change the statement to :

```
p->x; p++;
```

it would do exactly the same thing.

The order of precedence is actually exactly the same, as can be seen [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) - but it doesn't really matter.